# Blueimp jQuery file upload force iFrame Transport server response

Tags: ajax, json, perl, cgi, jquery-file-upload

I am using Blueimp JQuery File Upload, with the option forceIframeTransport: true, I am able to upload the file and form fields to a cross domain endpoint for processing.

However, the server response is something bother me for a long time.

I have come across a online material about the library:

http://missioncriticallabs.com/blog/lessons-learned-from-jquery-file-upload

I have followed the link's instruction but failed to get the server response correctly.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery("#newFile").fileupload({
        url: "https://mydomain/cgi-bin/get_file.cgi",
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        autoUpload: false,
        replaceFileInput: false
        done: function(e, data) {

            console.log("done");
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data.result);
        }
});
```

For now, my server endpoint is to print the JSON response out only:

```
#!C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe

use CGI;
use JSON;

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
#print header("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
my %rawText = (message => "Processed");
my $json = encode_json \%rawText;
print $json;
```

I have tried to print the header as "text/plain" and "application/json", but I cannot get the server response in my "done" function in the JS code.

My console.log(data.result) is always print "undefined".

I am quite fresh to the library and the concept behind,

so I will be much appreciated if anyone could guide me to use the library.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the widget work with Perl, you have to [implement a custom server-side upload handler](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup#using-jquery-file-upload-ui-version-with-a-custom-server-side-upload-handler). Your CGI script must return a JSON reponse in the format described in the documentation.

Fortunately, someone has already done the work for you. Have a look at the module [jQuery::File::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/jQuery::File::Upload) on CPAN.